# How to set the image clarity?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview

i am new i phone developer i am struggle with one problem i have use images in my app that images captured   through web services .  My problem is each images placed on each table cell that way i was compressed that image size in my cell size but image clarity was missing. please tell me how to set the image in cell  with clarity.

i am very suffer this problem please give me any suggestion for me.

hi i am working with Twitter, i got problem with images, i have tweet view have UITableview, it contains all tweet with user photo, if i load those photos in each cell when i scroll the UITableview, it scrolling very very slowly please suggest me to reduce the memory size of photos and scroll the UITableView fast.

i heard the thumbnail can reduce the memory size, does it.(if not which method i have to choose and what thumbnail method do's) if so how to do that in this code (table view cell code)
    i heard the thumbnail can reduce the memory size, does it.(if not which method i have to choose and what thumbnail method do's) if so how to do that in this code (table view cell code)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


if(!cell) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,10,58,60)] ;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[tweetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] image_url]]; //here Tweet is other class and image_url is method in the Tweet class

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[myImage setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:data]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:myImage];

[myImage release];  

}

return cell;
}

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the Lazyloading concept you can make your tableview scroll fastly.
Just download [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/downloads) class for lazyloading.

It is very easy to impelement.

```
 #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"  // Import this

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ------------------ 
     ------------------
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Then the picture clarity problem: Try to use the lower resolution images(50x50) like that